# The first key-exchange algorithm supported by the server is diffie-hellman-group1-sha1?

Tags: server

After I upgrated my serve to Ubuntu 16.04. Some warnings come out when I log on Linux serve(ubuntu 16.04) with putty.

Warning:    The first key-exchange algorithm supported by the server is diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, which is below the configured warning threshold. 
Do you want to continue with this connection?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

According to [Release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes):

> Support for the 1024-bit diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 key exchange is
>   disabled by default at run-time. It may be re-enabled using the
>   upstream instructions.

As mentioned [here](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) you need to use

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@legacyhost
```